# Reference view controller from custom UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a class called `MAGradeCell` that's a custom `UITableViewCell` class. Before I had the class and I was setting up the cell from inside the view controller (`MAController`), I just `configureHeaderCell`'d the `self` (which resolved to be the viewController.

Now that I have a custom class for the `UITableViewCell`, I can't refer to the viewController with `self`. Does that mean I should `alloc` and `init` a new viewController? Or do I have do something like `super` or import the viewController and get some interface property or something?

Comment: Use call back (Block), set it as a property in `MAGradeCell` and do the task in ViewController itself.

Comment: So like in these lines of code,
`if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            // 1
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                [viewController configureHeaderCell:self title:@"Hourly Forecast"];
            }`
How would I do a callback?

Comment: You can also use delegation

Comment: How? I'm sorry, I haven't used delegation before

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

in `MAGradeCell.h`

```
typedef void (^yourCallBack)(MAGradeCell *cell); //You may or may not use cell as parameter according to the need
```

Create it as a property

```
@property (readwrite, copy) yourCallBack callBack;
```

in `MAGradeCell.m`

```
- (void)someAction {
    if (self.callBack != nil) {

        self.callBack(self);       
    }
}
```

in cell configuration method

```
MAGradeCell *cell = ....

.....

cell.callBack = ^(MAGradeCell *gradeCell) {
        //Do the stuff
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, can you clarify how you were accessing viewController from UITableViewCell? Your custom cell should inherit everything that was available to UITableViewCell, but UITableViewCell doesn't have a view controller as one of its properties, so I'm a little confused how you were using it before in a way that you cannot apply to your subclass.

If you want the cell to retrieve some info from your viewController or notify it of something, or pass a message to it, you can use delegation like this:

You can create a delegate for the cell in MAGradeCell.h:

```
@protocol MAGradeCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)specialMethodWithCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell;

@end

@interface MAGradeCell:UITableViewCell

//...
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MAGradeCellDelegate>delegate;
//...

@end
```

Then in your MAGradeCel.m do the following:

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(specialMethodWithCell:)])
{
    [self.delegate specialMethodWithCell:self];
}
```

Then in your view controller's .h file make sure you declare that you'll be implementing this protocol and when you create your cell assign its delegate as self.

In this tutorial delegation is described a bit (as well some other really useful design patterns): http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns